# Fast way to check if a list of IP is in a list of IP-ranges (CIDR notation)

Tags: python, performance, ip-address, cidr, infoblox

I am looking for a fast way to check if IP addresses are part of a list of CIDR notated IP ranges. I've seen examples before use netaddr like:

```
from netaddr import IPNetwork, IPAddress

    for CIDR in CIDRLIST:
        if IPAddress(row[0]) in IPNetwork(CIDR):
            print('success')
```

However this solution is way too slow for my problem (800 IP ranges in CIDR and 500.000 IP adresses).

What could be a way to do this faster? I've read about using pytries, but I am not certain this is the solution.

Comment: use a list comprehension instead of a loop, and see if that improves the performance.

Comment: I wonder if you could implement "Van Emde Boas Tree" in python with any kind of performance.

Comment: I have the same problem -- I'm pretty sure the answer is to preprocess the list of blocks into a tree and then search the tree.  It's 40 years since I studied this stuff and I will have to go and consult Knuth Volume 3.  Thankfully some things in IT  don't change!  I don't think that vEB trees will work well as you need to build the tree with keys for every possible IP in the blocks.  (assuming that I have understood the Wikipedia article correctly).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Patricia/Radix tree/tries seem to be the answer.  I found them by searching for algorithms for looking up routing tables.

There is a python implementation [here](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/patricia-trie).

A little later:  I now have this working fine in Ruby:

```
require 'rpatricia'
require 'uoainfoblox'

ib = UoAIinfoblox.new ({'user' => 'xxxxx', 'password' => 'yyyy', 'host' => 'ipam.auckland.ac.nz'})

pt = Patricia.new

ib.get_networks('*roaming_network=true').each do |net, info |
  pt.add(net)
end

puts "'130.216.66.65 #{ pt.include?('130.216.66.65')}"
puts "130.216.5.128 #{pt.include?('130.216.5.128') }"
```

Infoblox is an IP Management system and UoAInfoblox is a wrapper around their web api.  So here I get a list of the roaming networks add them into a patricia tree and then check two IP addresses (that I know the status of).

Edit:  I have just found out from a friend who uses python and who teaches networking in our CS department that he used the python radix module in his research scripts. I know he was processing very large amounts of data from a /8 darkenet for CAIDA.